# Display turns on after I turn it off with AutoHotkey command

Tags: display, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, shortcuts, autohotkey

I use these two shortcuts to turn off the display:

```
Launch_Mail::
#T:: SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager
```

However, not infrequently, the display turns back on instantly after I use this hotkey. I press it again four to seven times, and it turns back on again. Then, I adjust the mouse a bit and try turning off. Sometimes, it works and sometimes, it doesn't.

Also, if I use the 'Launch_Mail' button to turn off the display and it doesn't, I use the '#T' shortcut. Most of the time, this works, but there are also times when that doesn't work either.

Is the problem with the mouse or something else? Should I also disable the mouse at the time of turning off the display.

I tried searching for this problem, but I couldn't find anything that was similar to my situation.

I don't know if this is much relevant, but I use Windows 8.1 and AHK v1.1.22.06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you're using the script from here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm which provides the following code:

```
#o::  ; Win+O hotkey that turns off the monitor.
Sleep 1000  ; Give user a chance to release keys (in case their release would wake up the monitor again).
; Turn Monitor Off:
SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager  ; 0x112 is WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF170 is SC_MONITORPOWER.
; Note for the above: Use -1 in place of 2 to turn the monitor on.
; Use 1 in place of 2 to activate the monitor's low-power mode.
return
```

I have to ask: Are you using the full script, or only that one line, because per the comments, -1 should be turning the monitor back on, suggesting your script might be running the off and on commands back to back.

Comment: I was using only that line. I've changed that. So, that shouldn't create any problem now. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: @Mahesh Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the release of the hotkey(s) that turns the display on again. This can be solved either by a "timeout", as in David Metcalfe's answer, or by simply waiting until the hotkey is released and only then turning the display off. The idiomatic way to do this is to use the `up` modifier (see the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#keyup)).

```
Launch_Mail Up::
#T Up:: SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you will wait for your keys to be released, just replace for the keys you want instead, here I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>:

```ahk
!Space::
    KeyWait Alt
    KeyWait Space
    SendMessage,0x112,0xF170,2,,Program Manager
Return
```